# Save result document to a specific folder

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to save a transformed xml to a specific folder say D:\user\target

I am using the below XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:result-document href="foo.xml">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help me on how to provide the above-specified folder path in href to save the xml. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<xsl:result-document href="file:/D:/user/target/foo.xml">
```